# Launch Screen Not Displaying & Weird White Bars around app - Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I'm using Meteor to create my project and I have inputted all possible key value pairs there are in the documentation for app icons and their launch screens

```
App.icons({
  //iPhone Icons
  'iphone_2x': 'icons/iphone_2x.png',
  'iphone_3x': 'icons/iphone_3x.png',
  'ipad': 'icons/ipad.png',
  'ipad_2x': 'icons/ipad_2x.png',
  'ipad_pro': 'icons/ipad_pro.png',
  'ios_settings': 'icons/ios_settings.png',
  'ios_settings_3x': 'icons/ios_settings_3x.png',
  'ios_spotlight': 'icons/ios_spotlight.png',
  'ios_spotlight_2x': 'icons/ios_spotlight_2x.png',

  //Android Icons
  'android_mdpi': 'icons/android_mdpi.png',
  'android_hdpi': 'icons/android_hdpi.png',
  'android_xhdpi': 'icons/android_xhdpi.png',
  'android_xxhdpi': 'icons/android_xxhdpi.png',
  'android_xxxhdpi': 'icons/android_xxxhdpi.png'
});

App.launchScreens({
  'iphone_2x': 'splash/iphone_2x.jpg',
  'iphone5': 'splash/iphone5.jpg',
  'iphone6': 'splash/iphone6.jpg',
  'iphone6p_portrait': 'splash/iphone6p_portrait.jpg',
  'iphone6p_landscape': 'splash/iphone6p_landscape.jpg',
  'ipad_portrait': 'splash/ipad_portrait.jpg',
  'ipad_portrait_2x': 'splash/ipad_portrait_2x.jpg',
  'ipad_landscape': 'splash/ipad_landscape.jpg',
  'ipad_landscape_2x': 'splash/ipad_landscape_2x.jpg',
  'android_mdpi_portrait': 'splash/android_mdpi_portrait.jpg',
  'android_mdpi_landscape': 'splash/android_mdpi_landscape.jpg',
  'android_hdpi_portrait': 'splash/android_hdpi_portrait.jpg',
  'android_hdpi_landscape': 'splash/android_hdpi_landscape.jpg',
  'android_xhdpi_portrait': 'splash/android_xhdpi_portrait.jpg',
  'android_xhdpi_landscape': 'splash/android_xhdpi_landscape.jpg',
  'android_xxhdpi_portrait': 'splash/android_xxhdpi_portrait.jpg',
  'android_xxhdpi_landscape': 'splash/android_xxhdpi_landscape.jpg'
});
```

When I put this in and run the command for running it on a mobile-device I get [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/44x9ub5lzwnrfgr/Photo%20May%2016,%209%2033%2018%20PM.png?dl=0) as well as the launch screen not showing up. Weird thing is that the app icon appears to show. The app icon as well as the launch screen both work on the iOS Simulator but not on an actual device.

[My Files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mudilrhw5x0v0og/Artboard%2026.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

If you check `meteor build --help`.

There is option for mobile setting named `--mobile-settings`.
So you have to run build using this option like this:

```
meteor build --mobile-settings mobile-config.js
```